# How to change the code generation style in Visual Studio 2022 to use "_" instead of "this."?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I am using Visual Studio 2022 to write C# code.

When adding a property to the constructor, then click on "Quick action and refactoring" and select "create and assign field for 'session'" visual studio would create the following

```
public class ExampleClass
{
    private ISession session;

    public ExampleClass(ISession session)
    {
        this.session = session;
    }
}
```

How can I change that style to use `_` instead of `this.`? so the generated code will then be

```
public class ExampleClass
{
    private readonly ISession _session;

    public ExampleClass(ISession session)
    {
        _session = session;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a .editorconfig file, which specifies your code style preferences. The VS code generation will then respect that.

See [this doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/naming-rules) for a run-down on how to create code style rules.

To enforce that all private fields must be camel-case with a leading underscore, try something like:

```
dotnet_naming_style.camel_case_leading_underscore.capitalization = camel_case
dotnet_naming_style.camel_case_leading_underscore.required_prefix = _

dotnet_naming_symbols.private_fields.applicable_kinds = field
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_fields.applicable_accessibilities = private

dotnet_naming_rule.private_fields_should_be_camel_case_leading_underscore.severity = warning
dotnet_naming_rule.private_fields_should_be_camel_case_leading_underscore.symbols = private_fields
dotnet_naming_rule.private_fields_should_be_camel_case_leading_underscore.style = camel_case_leading_underscore
```

You'll now get a warning if any private fields aren't in this style, and the code generation will also respect this:

[image: Screenshot showing VS respecting this rule]